# Android add action next and prev row/article

Tags: android

How to implement next and prev in android which the data get from database sqlite.
I want to as image in below:

[image]

I want to if I click button right so get to next row/article, if I click button left so get prev row/article.

What I need to do more, I just got here. This is my current query after listview. Below is  when I click an item from listview:

Query:

```
public Cursor getAllCategoryItem() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM myarticle";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        return cursor;
}
```

In activity:

```
Cursor c = db.getAllCategoryItem();
int count = c.getCount();
int position = c.getPosition();
Log.d("MyLog", "Count: " + count + ", Position: " + position);
```

and get in logcat is Count: 30, Position: -1;

I put button prev and next to menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.next_article) {
            // what code in here ?
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.prev_article) {
            // what code in here ?
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one of two ways.

1)Get all the items from the DB at the beginning, in order.  Store in an ArrayList.  Keep track of what the current item is, and when either button is pressed change the index into the array by 1 and update the display

2)Get only the item you need now via a WHERE clause.  When the user taps a button, request the new item via a WHERE clause.  Display the new item.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, For your suggest number one, I have get it from in previous activity is listview activity, In above is when I click item in listview. I have edit my post. Thanks.

Comment: Easiest way is probably method two. Pass the id of the item selected in the intent to the second activity and query the db for just that item in the sub-activity.  Then on next and prev you query for the previous or next item.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse via particular ID in Sqlite data base through query. But it seems much tedious.

So do one thing. On application start get all data from data base through cursor and store it in array. Then traverse in array.